# Split list by multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This LINQ and lambda expressions are killing me, so there is me again searching for help here :)

What I would like to do is transform `List<Order>` to `List<List<Order>>` having few things on mind.

There is some class `Order` with ID, Currency, and Ammount where basicaly only Currency has some role in this question.

```
class Order
{
    int ID;
    string Currency;
    money Ammount
}
```

Beside `Order` class there is some parameter for the maximum size of list.

```
int MaxListSize = 3;
```

And there is the list of orders

```
List<Order>
{
    1, EUR, 100
    2, EUR, 200
    3, USD, 34
    4, EUR, 12
    5, EUR, 54
    6, USD, 67
    7, EUR, 22
    8, USD, 67
    9, EUR, 89
    10, USD, 64
    11, EUR, 45
    12, USD, 65
    13, USD, 2
    14, EUR, 78
    15, USD, 79
    16, USD, 66
    17, EUR,  3
    18, EUR, 2
}
```

Transformation should look like this

```
List<List<Order>>
{
    {1, EUR, 100},  {2, EUR, 200}   {4, EUR, 12}
    {5, EUR, 54},   {7, EUR, 22},   {9, EUR, 89}
    {11, EUR, 45},  {14, EUR, 78},  {17, EUR,  3}
    {18, EUR, 2}
    {3, USD, 34},   {6, USD, 67},   {8, USD, 67}
    {10, USD, 64},  {12, USD, 65},  {13, USD, 2}
    {15, USD, 79},  {16, USD, 66}
}
```

translated to simple language each element of this output list sholud be list that contains only orders of same currency, and the max size of the element list should be param from the begining, MaxListSize.

And when I'm here, let's add a little bit more. Lets suppose we have some class OrderGroup which represent one item of output transformation few lines uper, but along with List it has property index.

```
class OrderGroup
{
    List<Order> OrderList
    int ListIndex
}
```

output should be

```
List<OrderGroup>
{
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{1, EUR, 100},    {2, EUR, 200}   {4, EUR, 12}}, ListIndex  = 1}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{5, EUR, 54}, {7, EUR, 22},   {9, EUR, 89}},  ListIndex  = 2}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{11, EUR, 45},    {14, EUR, 78},  {17, EUR,  3}}, ListIndex  = 3}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{18, EUR, 2}}, ListIndex  = 4}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{3, USD, 34}, {6, USD, 67},   {8, USD, 67}}, ListIndex  = 1}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{10, USD, 64},    {12, USD, 65},  {13, USD, 2}}, ListIndex  = 2}
     GroupOrder {OrderList = new List<Order> {{15, USD, 79},    {16, USD, 66}}, ListIndex  = 3}
}
```

Output is basicly same as first, plus there is index, which should depend on Currency. Each currency has it's own zero based index.

Any help woul be appricieted. I know it should be somehow done with Select() or SelectMany() extension methods, but I don't know how.

Thanx in advance:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically @BrokenGlass's answer adding a `GroupBy` and a `SelectMany` for completeness:

```
var results = orders.GroupBy(o => o.Currency)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((order, index) => new { Index = index, Order = order })
                                      .GroupBy(x => x.Index / MaxListSize)
                                      .Select(og => new OrderGroup() 
                                      {
                                         ListIndex = og.Key,
                                         OrderList = og.Select(x => x.Order).ToList()
                                       })
                                      .ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

To ensure the correct order in general cases, you could add an `.OrderBy(o => o.ID)` clause at the beginning of the query. But it doesn't matter in your test example.

Comment: Very nice! You need to rename the inner `g` in your `SelectMany` because it conflicts with the outer `g`, and remove an extra `)` at the end of `OrderList = g.Select(x => x.Order).ToList())` assignment to make it compile. But other than these simple typos, it produces the right results.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a LOT! Now I have to understand what is really going on in that query and how you've got the correct result :)

Answer (score 2):

To group your lists something like this should work:

```
var orderGroups = orders.Select((order, index) => new { Index = index, Order = order })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / MaxListSize)
                        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Order).ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

Transforming into an `OrderGroup` is now easy:

```
var orderGroups = orders.Select((order, index) => new { Index = index, Order = order })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / MaxListSize)
                        .Select(g => new OrderGroup() 
                         {
                            ListIndex = g.Key,
                            OrderList = g.Select(x => x.Order).ToList())
                         })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add a sorting part for completeness.

Comment: Sorting by `Currency` first and `ID` second seems to be enough.

Comment: @pad: You  can still have edge case that one list contains items with multiple currencies, so that won't be enough

Comment: I would sort the list by `Currency`, group by `Currency`, do splitting on inner lists and collect them into a big list. The OP wants separation between `EUR` and `USD` in the output.

Comment: @BrokenGlass
Fast I must say, but didn't do the trick. I've implemented your solution but I've got 6 instead od 7 items as result and got mixed EUR and USD Orders in one List wchich is not good. And second, take a look at 4th List in output, it has only one item.

Comment: @BrokenGlass pad is right. Multiple currencies in one list are not allowed

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky select, but it does what you need it to do:

```
var res = orders
    .GroupBy(o => o.Currency)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((o,i) => new {Ind = i, Order = o}))
    .GroupBy(p => new { Num = p.Ind/3, Curr = p.Order.Currency })
    .Select(g => new OrderGroup {ListIndex = g.Key.Num, OrderList = g.Select(x => x.Order).ToList()})
    .ToList();
foreach (var list in res) {
    Console.Write(list.ListIndex);
    foreach (var order in list.OrderList) {
        Console.Write("   {0} {1} {2};", order.ID, order.Currency, order.Ammount);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
0   1 EUR 100;   2 EUR 200;   4 EUR 12;
1   5 EUR 54;   7 EUR 22;   9 EUR 89;
2   11 EUR 45;   14 EUR 78;   17 EUR 3;
3   18 EUR 2;
0   3 USD 34;   6 USD 67;   8 USD 67;
1   10 USD 64;   12 USD 65;   13 USD 2;
2   15 USD 79;   16 USD 66;
```